# Deploy Hive tables to Dataproc cluster using Google Deployment Manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, google-deployment-manager

I would like to migrate my HIVE tables to an existing Dataproc cluster. Is there any way to deploy the tables using `Google Deployment Manager`. I have checked the list of supported resource types in GDM; could not locate a hive resource type. However, there is an instance of `dataproc.v1.cluster` available and I was able to successfully deploy a dataproc cluster. Now, is there any way to deploy my `HIVE` ddls within the cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For customizing your cluster we recommend [initialization actions](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/init-actions).

If your hive tables are all setup as `EXTERNAL` with data in GCS or BigQuery you could benefit from setting up a [metastore on Cloud SQL](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/tree/master/cloud-sql-proxy)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Used initialization actions and could deploy the scripts successfully after creating the cluster.

Comment: However, I am not able to run the script in an existing cluster, throws error -Method required for update.Can you give me an idea on the method required for updating the cluster resource ?

Comment: Dataproc does not support running init actions on a running cluster. I would encourage you to instead think about creating/deleting clusters on demand (in which case, consider Dataproc WorkflowTemplates as encapsulation of this pattern).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response

Comment: Hi Tix, Is there any way that we can create Hive tables on the go on an existing cluster (Without SSH)? As deleting the cluster will result in deletion of data on the cluster as well. There are A few tables that I'm maintaining and I may need to create tables using the data in the existing one.

Comment: @Tameem, you can use dataproc Hive jobs to run a hive script? Also, as noted in the answer, if you store data on GCS, declare your tables to be external, and use Cloud SQL for metastore then you can add/remove tables dynamically and they will persist between cluster creations. Hope this helps.